# NSDate - Getting Days of the Month (Not Days of the year)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Using NSDateComponents I know how to get the day component, but this gives me a value from 1 - 365, right? I need to get the days 1-30 of a specific month, how can I?

For example, I have an NSDate which might be 16th May. I want to be able to get the day, so it returns 16. Being the 16th day of that month (not the 16th day of the year).

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dateSaved"]];
```

However comps.day returns 1 when it should equal what the date is saved as, say 4.

Comment: Just to be sure: try to NSLog `comps`, and the date object that you did retrieve from the defaults.

Comment: I have NSLogged them, comps.day is always returning 1, and I can't log the saved date, how would I correctly? I have tried `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dateSaved"]);` I get null in the console. However I know that it doesn't return null because I use it in other places and set the date from it and it works.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the key is correct and you are calling this at the correct time in your code? This does seem to indicate that you're not getting the correct `NSDate` object.

Comment: I was so focused on other things thats just what I missed, thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `day` value of `NSDateComponents` gives you the day of month according to the given calendar:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@ / %d", date, comps.day);
```

gives

```
2012-02-04 15:27:36.682 testapp[1533:f803] 2012-02-04 14:27:36 +0000 / 4
```

although February, 4th would be the 35th day of the year.

Comment: Edited answer with response, hope you can help.